# Import Android project error

Tags: android

[image]

There no show of Run option. that is hide type.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the SDK installed for android 17. You can use the SDK Manager to install it. (it is the blue link in the error message)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the project is aimed towards Android sdk 17 and you dont have that sdk installed on your computer. Thats what the error towards the bottom suggests.